# Twitter API get Account tweet likes per day

Tags: twitter

I need to get the following stats for a twitter account on daily basis:
Likes per day
Replies per day
Retweets per day
Followers per day

Just like facebook graph API request "/me/insights/page_impressions?period=day"

I am trying twitter ads api but its not working. Can someone please tell me exact api and query.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the commercial Twitter [Engagements API](http://support.gnip.com/apis/engagement_api/) from Gnip. The Ads API is for promoted content.